# Vscode extension not running after importing lame

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, lame

I am trying to make a vscode extension which requires lame but every time I try to test the extension with lame imported it gives the error:

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.extension' failed: The module '\\?\c:\Users\Gus\Desktop\Code\extension\extension\node_modules\lame\build\Release\bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)..
```

I have tried npm rebuild and install but they dont have any effect.

Comment: I think if you have native dependencies, you need to rebuild them against the Node version that VSCode ships with, rather than the one you have installed locally. Take a look at the `deps` target in https://github.com/vshaxe/hashlink-debugger/blob/master/Makefile.

Comment: @Gama11 I have tried to rebuild it but the build keeps crashing.

Comment: Against the correct version though?

Comment: @Gama11 I tried 6.1.2, 6.1.1, 6.0.0, 5.0.0 and 4.0.0.